# Звуковая схема слов точка,уточка,дочка,удочка,бочка

Tags: фонетика

звуковая схема слов точка,уточка,дочка,удочка,бочка

Answer (score 2):

Смотря по какой программе занимаетесь

1.Гласный-красный квадрат, согласный твёрдый-синий, согласный мягкий-зелёный, над звонким жёлтый тругольник(звоночек)
http://nsportal.ru/sites/default/files/2012/1/algoritm_sostavleniya_zvukovoy_shemy.jpg

2.Гласные буквы обозначаются кружочками (большими точками),
Согласные твердые – одной полоской (черточкой),
Согласные мягкие – двумя полосками (двумя черточками).
Согласная становится мягкой, если после согласной буквы стоит смягчающая гласная – И, Я, Ю, Е, Е или мягкий знак Ь.

точка - . = - .   уточка . - . = - .  дочка - . = - .

Comment: А для чего эти звуковые схемы нужны, и в каком классе их изучают? Прошу прощения за оффтоп.

Comment: В начальной школе сейчас приучают различать звуки, для этого рисуют схемы.

Comment: Спасибо. Мы в третьем классе фонетический разбор точно уже делали, вроде бы даже с элементарным выделением редукций. Правда это вроде было сверх программы.